# Intent put Extra vs get data

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-intent

Hi I have RecycleView with posts I want wen click post go to activity 2.class and view some data that data in model var so what is the good send all data to intent or send post key and in activity 2 get data again from database by key
(I wnat to know best way only not code)(I use mvvm)

Comment: you can use the same intent to parse data to another activity. Or you can parse a key to the particular activity and on the onCreate function you can collect the key and collect the date from database or even server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider the size of data which you want to pass.
If the size of data is too much, I suggest you just pass the key, then on second activity request the data by using that key.